# How to write the urls in urls.py in django?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-urls

I am trying to write a class-based view which will take two inputs, say "city" and "bankname," and filter the data and send the results.

I am trying to write:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/bankcitydetail?city=mumbai&bankname=CENTRAL BANK OF INDIA.
```

How would I write the URL's path in urls.py?

Comment: I don't think this is something that `urls.py` is well suited for. That module is meant to structure the internal routing within your API, you should write a view that accepts these parameters and then bind that view to `/api/bankcitydetail/`

Comment: But how I will write that for example my urls is "http://example.com/api/products/4675/?category=clothing&max_price=10.00"

How write a url pattern for this in the form of something like url('^purchases/(?P<username>.+)/$', PurchaseList.as_view()),

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
   path('', views.x)
]
```

**x = Whatever your function is**

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you included the `bankcitydetail` in your url, you could just use:

`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/?city=mumbai&bankname=CENTRAL BANK OF INDIA`

That would be something like this:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('api/', views.api, name='api'),
]
```

If you want to use the `bankcitydetail` to specify the resource in the API, you could use path converters like in the example in Django's [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/urls/#example).